# I need help in understanding how itertools.product() works in this code snippet

Tags: python, dictionary

Problem statement - To create and display all combinations of letters, selecting each letter from a different key in a dictionary.

```
import itertools
d ={'1':['a','b'], '2':['c','d']}
for i in itertools.product(*[d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys())]):
    print(''.join(i))
```

In given code, I am confused as to why the author used "*". I don't quite understand working of expression passed inside the product().
Especially if we want to perform cartesian product operation then why is author using keys to map them. I am quite new to python and need some guidance regarding these complicated functions.

Comment: Just start from the inside out. `[d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys())]` evaluates to the list: `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`. Using `*` spreads the inner lists as arguments. It's the same as `product(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'])`

Comment: Also, you could probably simplify: `for i in itertools.product(*d.values()):`

Comment: So mark please correct me if i wrong, instead of passing them as arguments, can we not just simply map them like product(d).

Comment: `map()` will end up calling product multiple times. That would be a different result than calling product *once* with multiple arguments.

Comment: Adding to @Mark earlier comment - the `*` (star) is just `unpacking` the `values` in dict.